# Deploy JSS App on sitecore instance

Tags: sitecore-client, jss

While bulding JSS app i am getting an error.

Command : JSS Build

Error:

> ERROR in Error during template compile of 
>          'StyleguideAngularLazyLoadingModule'
>
> Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'JssModule' was called

The above error is blocking me to deploy my app on the Sitecore.

Additionaly can any one share a link to create good production quality website(powered with Sitecore) demo in JSS Angular.

Thank you,

Comment: Take a look in this sample app that uses JSS made by Sitecore Demo team -> https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Omni .

Comment: Thank you, Is it compatible with Sitecore 9.0.0.0  rev171002?

Comment: I must say, getting JSS with Angular running seems to be frustrating. I installed JSS last Friday (1/4). Yesterday I created an Angular app following the Quick Start, and ran into bug #90. OK, so then I tried to clone the JSS dev branch, build and deploy the Angular sample. But now running into the AOT bug, even after changing the package.json to ^7.0.4. We are currently using Sitecore 7.2, but developing new apps in Angular, and I am trying to make the case that we need to move to 9.1, but can't seem to even put together a simple demo of SC 9.1 with Angular.... :-(

Comment: sorry to put this as an answer. I don't have those many reputations to put it as a comment. I updated the reference to 11.0.0 as suggested by Kamsar. But I am still getting the same error.
Am I missing something? The Sitecore version is 9.0.2 Thanks for your help > { "_from": "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-angular@11.0.0", "_id": "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-angular@11.0.0", "_inBundle": false, "_integrity": "sha512-kRKGQ7peNRT41dyWyQGo9qQq/WIO23BCFlxx87i5RyWuiZnLOis5lsqBw4iDNz2a4hO2eqZOTb9hbp+327GbLA==", "_location": "/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-angular", "_phantomChildren": {}, "_requested": { "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by an AOT bug in `@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-angular@11.0.1`.

Pinning your dependency to `11.0.0` (with no `~` nor `^`) should resolve the issue for now. This is probably related to [this PR](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/pull/83)

Comment: Very cool, Kam! I downgraded to 11.0.0 and all is good. For now, since this is only at the feature demo stage, using 11.0.0 is good. Once we move into the real code, hopefully some of the Angular problems should work better. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Hey could you please confirm i just need to update the following line in package.json to@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-angular": "~11.0.0"  and run npm install. if so, then i  am still acing the same issue.

Comment: Hey I did the same but no luck still facing the same issue. Tried it both ways by pinning only angular dependency and pinning all packages dependencies(from ^11.0.0.1 to ~11.0.0.0)

Comment: @Pankaj do not use `~` or `^` - you want 11.0.0 and _only_ 11.0.0.